# postgres upsert query for batch

Tags: postgresql

I am running the following upsert query. I looked at the syntax it looks good but it is failng.

`insert into ingest.items (item_id, company_id, item_name,qoh, last_modified_date, create_date) values ('1', '1', 'shirt','100', now(), now()), ('2', '2', 'shirt','100', now(), now()),('3', '3', 'shirt','100', now(), now()) on conflict on constraint item_constraint do update set {(item_name='roundnext1', qoh='500'),(item_name='roundnext2', qoh='500')};`

If i run the below query it is working.

`INSERT INTO ingest.items  (item_id, company_id, item_name,qoh, last_modified_date, create_date) VALUES ('1', '1', 'trouser','100', now(), now()),('2', '2', 'pant','100', now(), now()) ON CONFLICT on constraint item_constraint DO UPDATE SET item_id=EXCLUDED.item_id, item_name=EXCLUDED.item_name, qoh=EXCLUDED.qoh`

Comment: The syntax of the first statement doesn't look good at all. What are these `{}` and `()` doing there?

Comment: constructed it using https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html

Comment: I tried this as well still failing
insert into ingest.items (item_id, company_id, item_name,qoh, last_modified_date, create_date) values ('1', '1', 'shirt','100', now(), now()), ('2', '2', 'shirt','100', now(), now()),('3', '3', 'shirt','100', now(), now()) on conflict on constraint item_constraint do update set (item_name, qoh) =('roundnext1', '500'),(item_name, qoh) = ('roundnext2', '500'),(item_name, qoh) = ('roundnext3', '500');

Comment: That is also bad syntax. What is the point of trying all kinds of bad syntax and watching it fail? Your question shows that you know the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

When reading the syntax diagrams, brackets and curly braces are not to be taken literally.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/notation.html):

> The following conventions are used in the synopsis of a command: brackets (`[` and `]`) indicate optional parts. (In the synopsis of a Tcl command, question marks (`?`) are used instead, as is usual in Tcl.) Braces (`{` and `}`) and vertical lines (`|`) indicate that you must choose one alternative. Dots (`...`) mean that the preceding element can be repeated.